# If $G$ is a finite group such that $H,K\leq G$ and $HK\leq G$, can we say that $G$ is solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

Question: Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$ such that $HK\leq G$.

I believe I have seen before that we can claim that $G$ is a solvable group, but I can't think about how to show it.  Maybe since $HK\leq G$, then we can say, WLOG that $H\leq G$ and $K\trianglelefteq G$, and then try and play with the derived series?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let $G$ be a non-solvable group. Take $H = \{1\}$ and $K = \{1\}$. Then $HK \leq G$ and $G$ is not solvable. Maybe this is not the question you really wanted to ask.

Comment: "We may assume $K$ normal in $G$". No, you may not. Just because $HK$ is a subgroup, you do not know that either normalizes the other, let alone that one of them is normal in $G$.

Comment: For an example where $HK$ is a group but neither normalizes the other, let $G=S_4$, let $H$ be the stabilizer of $4$) (isomorphic to $S_3$), and let $K$ be the copy of the dihedral group of order $8$ obtained by letting it act on the corners of a square, numbered 1 through 4. Their intersection is of order $2$ (only two rigid transformations fix a given vertex), so their product has order $(6)(8)/2 = 24$. Thus, $HK=S_4$. But $K$ does not normalize $H$ and $H$ does not normalize $K$ (and neither is normal in $S_4$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I interpret your question as follows: If $HK\le G$ for *all* $H,K\le G$, then $G$ is solvable? (assuming $|G|<\infty$)
The answer is yes. Let $H$ and $K$ be Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Then $HK\le G$ implies $H=K$. Hence, every Syow subgroup is normal and $G$ is nilpotent. In particular, $G$ is solvable.

(In general, groups with this property are called *Iwasawa* groups or sometimes *modular* groups (see Wikipedia)).

Comment: Why does if $H,K\in Syl_p(G)$ then $HK\leq G\implies H=K$?

Comment: The formula $|HK|=|H:H\cap K||K|$ shows that $HK$ is a $p$-subgroup which cannot be bigger than a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since $H\le HK$, we must have $H=HK$ and similarly $K=HK$.